# polynomial product and roots, I need help to this exercise

Tags: polynomials, proof-explanation

**Theorem 9.6** *Let K be a field, $b(x)$ a nonzero polynomial in $K[x]$ of degree $n$, and $\gamma$ an element of $K$. Then there is a unique polynomial $q(x)$ in $K[x]$ of degree less then $n$ and a unique element $r$ of $K$ such that*
\begin{align*}
b(x) = (x-\gamma)q(x)+r
\end{align*}

1. Use Theorem 9.6 Re-write $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ in terms of $x-\gamma$ and multiply the two expressions together to express $f(x)g(x)$ in terms of $x-\gamma$ and a constant.
2. Use the fact that $x-\gamma$ divides this product to show that it divides the constant.
3. Deduce that the constant is 0, and from this conclude that $x-\gamma$ divides $f(x)$ or $g(x)$

So first i Want to Re-write f(x) and g(x) in terms of $x-\gamma$ so this is right?
\begin{align*}
(x-\gamma) = \frac{-r}{g(x)}
\end{align*}

Then I multiply the two expressions together 
\begin{align*}
(x-\gamma)^2 = (\frac{-r}{g(x)})^2
\end{align*}

But I don't know how to continue ? any tips?

Comment: What is the statement that you want to prove?

Comment: Let $K$ be a field, and let $\gamma$ be an element of $K$. Suppose $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are two polynomials in $K[x]$. If $x-\gamma$ divides the produt $f(x)g(x)$, then $x-\gamma$ divides at least one of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) By your theorem 9.6, you know that you have two polynomials $p(x),q(x)$ and two elements of $K$ $r,s$ such that $f(x)=(x-\gamma)p(x)+r$ and $g(x)=(x-\gamma)q(x)+s$. Multiply this and get a new expression for $f(x)g(x)$.

2) Recognize an equality which looks like the one in 9.6. By uniqueness, look at what the constant is.

3) Conclude.

During these three steps, you are not allowed to write things like $\frac{1}{g(x)}$ since polynomials have no inverses in general (they have in a more complicated algebraic structure, which is not involved in this exercice). By $p(x)$ divides $s(x)$, we just mean that $s(x)=p(x)q(x)$ for some polynomial $q(x)$.

Comment: okay, so 1) When I multiply the two polynomials I get $f(x)g(x) = ((x-\gamma)p(x) + r)((x-\gamma)q(x) + s)$ and I know that because $(x-\gamma)$ divides the product, then the constant need to be 0. and then I can conclude that (x-\gamma) divides either $f(x)$ or $g(x)$??

Comment: Yes, since the constant is the product $rs$, and that since $K$ is a field you have necessarily $r=0$ or $s=0$, which is precisely $(x-\gamma)$ divides $f(x)$ or $(x-\gamma)$ divides $g(x)$.

Comment: What do u mean by "since $K$ is a field you have necessarily $r=0$ or $s = 0$"? :)

Comment: In a general ring you can't say that $ab=0$ implies that $a=0$ or $b=0$ (think about the matrices with $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$), so you have to add this little argument. It follows from the fact that if $r\neq0$, then $r$ has a multiplicative inverse and from $rs=0$ you get $r^{-1}rs=r^{-1}0$ which implies $s=0$.